# Linq query for dynamically value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an `IQueryable` collection of `Employee` objects which has `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Department` in it. I'm passing a string of `LastName` separated by comma. I want to use `where` clause to filter data which has `LastName` selected as `"Sharma,Gupta"`. Can someone help me out?

Employee class

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string EmpID { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmpData(String filterExpression)
{
    IQueryable<Employee> data = GetEmployeeData();
    data = from da in data
           where (da.LastName == "Sharma")
           select da;
    return data;

}
```

In the above method I can query a single value. `filterExpression` contains list of `LastName` separated by a comma. Can someone guide me how to use `filterExpression` in `where` clause?

Answer (score 2):

Split your string and use `.Contains`:

```
names = filterExpression.Split(",");
IQueryable<Employee> data = GetEmployeeData();
data = from da in data
       where names.Contains(da.LastName)
       select da;
```

As you return the entire object and do not project only parts of it using the method syntax might be more readable:

```
return GetEmployeeData().Where(item => names.Contains(item.LastName));
```

Comment: @Nilesh - you are welcome :) please consider marking question as solved and upvoting :)

Answer (score 0):

If your filterExpression is a string, with the names separated by commas, then you'd want to change your query to check if the last name is in the list of names in filterExpression like this:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmpData(String filterExpression)
{
    List<string> names = filterExpression.Split(",");
    return GetEmployeeData().Where(names.Contains(da.LastName));
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that it compiles?